# compile and test-compile fail

Tags: java, maven

I have two maven projects, one named `common` and another `core`. `core` depends on `common`. The dependency span both `src` and `test` code in `core`. Here's the file structure:

```
common/
    src/main/java/
         ...
    src/test/java/
         ...
    pom.xml

core/
    src/main/java/
         ...
    src/test/java/
         ...
    pom.xml
```

Common's pom is setup pretty simply:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.uttt.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                ...
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My core's `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.uttt.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uttt.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <scope>?</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                ...
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The problem is, when the scope on my dependency on `common` in `core/pom.xml` is `compile` or `provided`, the `compile` maven goal passes but `test-compile` doesn't - with compilation errors in the test code. When the scope is `test`, the neither goals passes - with compilation errors in the source code.

Anyone have any clues on how to setup my poms such that `compile` and `test-compile` succeed?

Comment: It doesn't look like a multimodule project, so the code could be out of sync. Did you run `mvn install` on the `common`-project before running `mvn test` on `core`? btw, the scope should be `compile` for the dependency, which is already the default, so you don't have to include the scope.

Comment: Yes, I've ran `mvn clean install` on common. I navigated to my m2 repo for a sanity check and confirmed the jar's existence. I initially thought it should be `compile`. `mvn clean compile` runs just fine in that case. `mvn clean test-compile` doesn't. Maven complains about a bunch of `cannot find symbol`s in my test code regarding classes that should be imported from `common`.

Comment: But does the common jar contain the expected class files (it's a matter of unzipping and searching for that file)? Or did you make a typo in your core code?